# Options for replicating a large amount of data to many subscribers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I'm using transactional replication and have run into a problem. The problem is there's a table that stores Inventory QTY Per Site data, and it's huge. It represents 90% of the total data. Each subscriber is located at a different site, and really only needs the inventory qtys for the site its located at. The initial snapshot takes a really long time because of this big table, so i'm looking for some solutions to this.

Here's some possible solutions i've thought of so far:

**Initialize snapshots from a backup.** This would be perfect, except for when a subscriber needs to be reinitialized. The sites are in a country that has unreliable internet - so the chance of a subscriber going offline for a long period is pretty high.

**Compress snapshot** - according to the documentation they recommend a reliable network, which isn't available.

**Filter the big table by site** in other words, only copy the data for the subscriber's site. I looked this up and apparently it's only available for merge replication? Maybe switching to merge replication would be a better option so that i can use parameterized row filter?

**Dont replicate the big table, copy it with a job instead** - copy it on demand or based on a schedule. However, i don't think there's a way to enable the table for transactional replication after copying the data like this, so it would get out of sync until you ran the job again.

Is anyone aware of other possible solutions to this. I'm open to any suggestions, even switching to merge replication if that would solve the problem.

Comment: Does the big table have a SiteID column or some column indicating which site a row belongs to?

Comment: Yeah it has a Location Code field. I'm thinking I can do a parameterized row filter using the HOST_NAME(). This would require a subquery to find the physical computer name that the location code is mapped to.

Comment: If you want to stick with Transactional Replication, what you could do is create multiple publications, using Static Row Filters, 1 publication per Location, and have each site subscribe to its associated filtered publication.

Comment: We've decided to switch to one-way merge replication, so that we can filter the data per subscriber using the same publication.

Just out of curiosity, it seems like one-way merge is more efficient than transactional since it only replicates the end result, instead of each transaction at a time. So if one row is updated thousands of times you'd have to replicate those 1000 updates, whereas with merge you'd only replicate the final state of the data after the 1000 updates (assuming not continous updating). At least that's what i think...

Comment: @Makolyte - you are absolutely correct in your final statement. From TechNet: "The application requires net data change rather than access to intermediate data states. For example, if a row changes five times at a Subscriber before it synchronizes with a Publisher, the row changes only once at the Publisher to reflect the net data change (that is, the fifth value)."